# Icon not appearing in browser

Tags: html, icons, favicon

I am making a simple HTML webpage, I am trying to add an icon in the browser tab, I can get the icon to appear if I use a picture from online. However when I try to use a local file the icon is not visible. Here is what I used to try and embed the icon

```
<link rel="icon" href="/icon.ico">
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your code works in recent Firefox.

Maybe the problem is that leading slash in the path makes browser search it in server root directory?

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" href="icon.ico" />
```

Comment: I have tried changing that. As well as just using the full file path, and using the server IP with /icon.ico at the end